# Sound lag on Xubuntu

Tags: sound, xubuntu, acer, aspire-one

I am having some problems with the audio on my computer, it sounds laggie playing anything (YouTube, VLC, gmusicbrowser), Music or Video.

Drivers:
PCI Devices
Host bridge
Intel Corporation System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) (rev 07)

VGA compatible controller
Intel Corporation System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) Graphics Controller (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

Audio device
Intel Corporation System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) HD Audio Controller (rev 07)

Computer: Acer Aspire One

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulseaudio is probably the problem on a slow pc. You can try to disable it, as most audio software can use directly alsa audio layer .
Copy and run these 2 commands in a terminal:

```
mkdir ~/.pulse
echo autospawn=no > ~/.pulse/client.conf
```

then reopen session (or reboot) and test.
The sound applet will be disabled but you can install and use gnome-alsamixer to set volume.

If you want to revert to pulseaudio, just run `echo autospawn=yes > ~/.pulse/client.conf`

Comment: It worked, video and music playing flawless now.
Thanks